# Переполнение переменной int при вводе

Tags: c++, обработка-ошибок

Подскажите пожалуйста, как лучше проверять переменную на переполнение при вводе её из консоли

Например для кода

```
int i;

cin >> i;
cout << i << endl;
```

Можно получить:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вводить как строку и проверять...

Comment: Спасибо, врубился =)

Comment: Правда у меня получается через чур сложный способ проверки...
В моей программе, мне придется считать число в     int, перевести его в строку, проверить поместиться ли оно в     int, потом если поместиться, обратно в     int...
Возможно есть что-то проще?
P.S. Проверять решил переводом INT_MAX в строку и сравнением введеного с ним, не забывая про минус.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибку можно определить или через функцию good() или просто проверив поток в условном операторе. Но обязательно после определения того, что произошла ошибка, надо убрать ошибки из потока используя функции clear() и ignore(), иначе последующий ввод не будет работать:

```
int a;
cout<<"Input a=";
cin>>a;

if( cin.good() )  // if ( cin )
{
    cout<<"Correct input a="<<a<<endl;
}
else
{
    cout<<"Error input"<<endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore();
}

int b;
cout<<"Input b=";
cin>>b;
cout<<"b="<<b<<endl;
```

Пример результата работы программы:
[image: Проверка ввода]

Если убрать очистку, строки clear() и ignore(), то последующий ввод в переменную b пролетает без остановки. Пример такой работы:
[image: Отсутствие очистки]

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему используя после ввода проверку

```
if (cin.good())
```

Comment: Да, но это отработка *не только* переполнения, а вы спрашивали именно о нем.